# Rotate Image 90 degrees

Tags: php, image

I am able to upload the image to a web server and store the location in the database as follows:

```
/123cb2kbls.62452152.jpg
```

Then, I am able to retrieve the location of the file and display it to the web browser with no problem as follows:

```
$row['pic_loc'] // has a value of '/123cb2kbls.62452152.jpg'

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $width = 900;
    $display_height = $width*$row["height_ratio"];
    $source = $row["pic_loc"];

    echo "<p><td><img src='" . $source     ."' width=$width height=$display_height></p></td>";          
}
```

My challenge is that I cannot get the `imagerotate()` to flip the image 90 degrees using the following code inside my `while()` loop:

```
$rotate90 = imagerotate($source,90,0);
echo "<p><td><img src='" . $rotate90   ."' width=$display_height height=$width></p></td>";
```

The only thing that happens is that I see the outline of a file that has been rotated 90-degrees, but no image displays.

Comment: Inspect the resulting HTML and verify the image source is correct.  I suspect `$rotate90` is not correct.

Comment: [imagerotate()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php) requires a image resource, not a direct URL, you still have to read/write the file from/to storage to apply this processing. also be mindful that there can be two issues, meta data orientation, and pixel data rotation.

Comment: No, you have to load the file from disk, rotate it, and save it back to disk. what kind of data is `$row["pic_loc"]`? is it a URL, filename, full file path? If the file is a JPEG on disk, you would use `imagecreatefromjpeg()` to read from disk first, then `imagerotate()` to perform your rotation then `imagejpeg()` to write the rotated image back to disk. I'd suggest keeping the original if possible, but not mandatory.

Comment: Scuzzy - thank you. That points me in the right direction.

Comment: Look at `Example #1 Rotate an image 180 degrees` in http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php it has the exact same three steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from what you have *(and I could be wrong)*, I think maybe css would be better for this instead of using a bunch of server power, especially if you are not saving a permanent rotation to the images:

```
<style>
.pic-loc-rotate img {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
</style>

<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):
    $width  = 900;
    $height = ($width * $row["height_ratio"]) ?>

    <td class="pic-loc-rotate">
        <p><img src="<?php echo $row["pic_loc"] ?>" width="<?php echo $width ?>" height="<?php echo $height ?>" /></p>
    </td>

<?php endwhile ?>
```

Rotate via CSS:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate

---

If you really want to have the images rotated via the server (but don't want to store them), you can use the output buffer and `base64_encode()`, but CSS is definitely a better solution:

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):
    # Start the buffer so the image doesn't output to the browser yet
    ob_start();
    # Fetch your image and rotate it
    # Create to the buffer
    imagejpeg(imagerotate(imagecreatefromjpeg($row["pic_loc"]), 90, 0));
    # Encode the contents of the output buffer to base64
    $imageBase64    =   base64_encode(ob_get_contents());
    # Clear buffer
    ob_end_clean();
    # Do your other stuff
    $width  = 900;
    $height = ($width * $row["height_ratio"]) ?>

        <td class="pic-loc-rotate">
            <p><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo $imageBase64 ?>" width="<?php echo $width ?>" height="<?php echo $height ?>" /></p>
        </td>

<?php endwhile ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, Rasclatt! I was using hover css with -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg), but that was not the best solution. You gave me the best solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You must create the image from `imagecreatefromjpeg` as follows

```
$imurl = "../images/sample.jpg";
$file = imagecreatefromjpeg($imurl); //http://nz2.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php
$rotim = imagerotate($file, 90, 0);   //http://nz2.php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php      
imagejpeg($rotim, $imurl);
```

Comment: Thank you Dante. So how do I echo imagejpeg($rotim, $source) to the web browser, please? I tried echo imagejpeg($rotim, $source) but it did not work

Comment: Also wondering how that was done.. did you manage in the end ?